# Facebook, Google+ and twitter like button on website

Tags: facebook, twitter, google-plus

how to add Facebook, Google+ and twitter like/share button on my website, to sharing details of my website. because, i tried the following code in my website for google+. But, it's only sharing my website pic not the description and title of my website

```
<meta itemprop="name" content="MySMSBuddy">
<meta itemprop="description" content="Description of my webpage">
<meta itemprop="image" content="http://eravikant.com/images/image.png">

<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
</script>
```

Any help and idea will be appreciated !!!

Comment: Have you done a search for these, such as "Google+ button" or "Facebook Like button" on StackOverflow? Those very simple queries come up with a whole slew of previously asked questions. I imagine you could get a lot of help from reading some of those.

Comment: i searched.. but, my problem is, when i'm trying to share my website details using google+ it's only showing pic not title and description of my website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those sites use the title tag for page title, and meta name="description" for description (not itemprop="description".

```
<title>Title of your page</tile>
<meta name="description" content="Description of your page" />
```

For Facebook, you can also use open graph meta tags:

```
 <meta property="og:title" content="Title"/>
 <meta property="og:description" content="Description"/>
```